# How do I use a showroom model of an iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone

A friend of mine bought an iPhone 4S. It was a showroom model and it came with his limitations. You can't delete or move around apps. What does he need to do to get rid of this demo-modus. Or is it irreversible?

**EDIT:**
He bought the iPhone in Belgium (so, it has no sim lock)

Comment: I would suggest he return to the point of purchase and ask them to provide a fully-functional phone.

Comment: This might be a more useful question if you can add which vendor / country set up the phone as some go further than others. It does beg the question why not go back and have the seller fix things since your friend will want the phone to work and be sold correctly rather than perhaps be listed as a "missing" demo unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest doing a **DFU restore**. You can do this by:

1. Plug your iPhone into a computer running the latest version of [**iTunes**](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).
2. Hold the home button and the sleep/wake button for exactly **8 seconds**.
3. After this 8 seconds is up, release the sleep/wake button, but continue to hold the home button until iTunes recognizes your iPhone.
4. Then, choose the **Restore** option (this should be the only option) and wait for iTunes to download the necessary software and restore your iPhone.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple erase all content and settings clear this up? A DFU restore is overkill for clearing profile restrictions and loaded content from a device.

Comment: Not necessarily. The question didn't specify where exactly the device came from, but when I was at Apple they had us load special builds of iOS on to floor model iPhones. It wasn't just profile settings - they designed a special firmware/iOS just for the floor models. If you want to be sure everything from the phone is blown away, I'd go with a DFU restore.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: If you want to get out of demo mode (and can jailbreak the device) here how it's done:

- Jailbreak the device.
- Edit `/private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.demo-settings.plist` file and set "LockIcons" and "StoreDemoMode" to false.
- Remove `/var/mobile/Demo.mov`

You could always use those steps in reverse to make it a demo phone.

ps. Accept Matt's solution, it's easier, safer and can't go wrong.